# security of obfuscated dlls

Tags: c, security, dll

I have a heavily obfuscated native win32 dll with unknown functionality and it does not seem to call any function from other dlls. My question is that theoretically is this code able to modify its code to do any harm. Sub questions:
- is the code part of a dynamically loaded dll read only by default or is it writable?
- if a code does not use any other dll it is still able to
do something that requires some code from a system dll?
How could it load another dll and find a function if the function for loading dlls is not loaded by default?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this code able to modify its code to do any harm.

Yes. And indeed it may do harm without even needing to modify itself.

> Is the code part of a dynamically loaded dll read only by default or is it writable?

By default, DLLs are capable of modifying themselves. They need to call `VirtualProtect` in order to do so, but that's perfectly possible.

> If a code does not use any other dll it is still able to do something that requires some code from a system dll?

The DLL can just load any system DLL and call whatever functions it chooses.

> How could it load another dll and find a function if the function for loading dlls is not loaded by default?

By calling `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. If the DLL really imports nothing at all then it's tricky to get hold of `GetProcAddress`. But not impossible. If Windows manages to do it, then surely the DLL can as well. One thing it could do is read the in-memory contents of the kernel32 DLL which is loaded into every process. It could parse the PE export table and use that to find the address of `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: I have no idea how stack overflow works so I am just going to reply here, sorry:) how can it call loadlibrary if the current version does not call any function. How could it call virtualprotect if it does not know the address of virtualprotect. This is the part that I dont understand.

Comment: Both of those functions are in kernel32 which is loaded into all processes. Granted, if your DLL has an empty import table, then it's going to need to find the address of `GetProcAddress` by some nefarious means. But it's certainly possible. Once it has `GetProcAddress` then it can get to anything. How have you determined that this DLL "does not seem to call any function from other dlls"?

Comment: To be honest I find your answers too vague but it is probably my fault. I don't know what I expected.

Comment: Well, I'd say that the vagueness of the answers matches that of the questions.  ;-)

Comment: Note to myself, do not write answers on a mobile because you will press enter accidentally when the comment is not finished and will look like a douche. Sorry about that. Back to topic: the current code does not call anything, there is no call or similar instruction in it, it only jumps around inside the dll. There is nothing imported in this dll. How could it parse the content of kernel32dll in memory? Is it mapped to a specific address?

Comment: Even if it's not mapped to a common address the DLL could search memory for kernel32. Start by looking up the call stack.